# Disable unzipping the zipped response in Ngnix

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have 5 micro-services that are up and running. One of them is an nginx server that acts as a gateway( reverse proxy for other services). There is another service called 'web' that is an nginx server that serves all the client side static bundles. I have enabled gzipping in the web nginx server. But when the compressed response comes through the gateway nginx server, it decompresses the files and sends them back to the client. I tried setting `gzip off` and `gunzip off` in gateway nginx server but it is not working.

Here is the configuration of the web-nginx server:

```
gzip on;
gzip_comp_level 3;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
gzip_min_length  100;
gzip_buffers  4 32k;
```

Here is the configuration for the gateway ngnix server:

```
gzip off;
gunzip off;
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `gzip_proxied  any;` to the backend nginx servers (*serving static files*)

*Compress data even for clients that are connecting to us via proxies,
identified by the "Via" header (required for CloudFront/Cloudflare).*

The default value is *off* which disables compression for all proxied requests, ignoring other parameters; For more info checkout the [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake that, i failed to forward the header using `proxy_pass` from proxy server to actual server. With help of above answer. it worked.